# What utilities allow you to debug a process without pausing execution?

Tags: linux, gdb

I was just reading this answer on StackOverflow, [*"How can you debug a process using gdb without pausing it?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28511887/124486)

> The Linux kernel provides some support for this via `PTRACE_SEIZE`, but gdb doesn't use this yet.  There's a [bug in bugzilla you can track, *"Bug 15250 - use `PTRACE_SEIZE` and `PTRACE_INTERRUPT`"*](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15250)

I was able to find `PTRACE_SEIZE` documented in `man ptrace`,

> `PTRACE_SEIZE` (since Linux 3.4): Attach  to  the process specified in pid, making it a tracee of the calling process.  Unlike `PTRACE_ATTACH`, `PTRACE_SEIZE` does not stop the process.  Group- stops are reported as `PTRACE_EVENT_STOP` and `WSTOPSIG(status)` returns the stop signal.  Automatically attached  children  stop  with  `PTRACE_EVENT_STOP`  and `WSTOPSIG(status)`  returns  `SIGTRAP`  instead of having `SIGSTOP` signal delivered to them.  `execve(2)` does not deliver an extra `SIGTRAP`.  Only a `PTRACE_SEIZE`d process can accept `PTRACE_INTERRUPT` and `PTRACE_LISTEN` commands.  The "seized" behavior just described is inherited by children that are  automatically  at‐ tached  using `PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK`, `PTRACE_O_TRACEVFORK`, and `PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE`.  addr must be zero.  data contains a bit mask of ptrace options to activate immediately. Permission to perform a `PTRACE_SEIZE` is governed by a ptrace access mode `PTRACE_MODE_ATTACH_REALCREDS` check; see below.

That raises the question if `PTRACE_SEIZE` isn't supported by gdb, what tooling (if any) does support this functionality on Linux?